# How to assign tasks to a couple of days with selecting the most valuable tasks via optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I've readed all the examples of optaplanner, but our scenario is:
1, we have lot of tasks e.g:100 tasks
2, we have to days to finish these tasks
3, each task takes around 1hr to 1.5hr, so in two day it is not able to finish all these tasks
4, the time for switching task depends on the tasks locations, i.e: how long will the task take depends the previous task's location.

we are using optaplanner to optimize the tasks in order to finish more taska within two days.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **overconstrained planning** (see docs). Basically, if not all tasks can be assigned, don't assign some tasks. A combination of nullable=true and a medium constraint that penalizes unassigned tasks fixes that.

As for making the task's length depend on the location, see the task assignment example, there the length depends on the task's affinity. You can use the same principle in a matchWeighter.